# Spring HATEOAS client ignore null links - "Template must not be null or empty!" exception

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-hateoas

I'm accessing a HATEOAS API provided by a 3rd party and for some reason the response we receive from them contains links with null values for href. This throws an exception. I can not change the response as I have no control over this API. Is there any way around this problem?

Below is an example of what the JSON looks like:

```
{
    "_embedded": {
        "example": [{ ... }]
    }
    "_links": {
        "next": {
            "href": null
        },
        "prev": {
            "href": null
        },
        "self": {
            "href": "https://bag.basisregistraties.overheid.nl/api/v1/panden"
        }
    }
}
```

When I make the request using the RestTemplate I get an IllegalArgumentException with the message "Template must not be null or empty!"

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Template must not be null or empty!
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.hasText(Assert.java:284)
    at org.springframework.hateoas.UriTemplate.<init>(UriTemplate.java:56)
    at org.springframework.hateoas.Link.<init>(Link.java:94)
    at org.springframework.hateoas.hal.Jackson2HalModule$HalLinkListDeserializer.deserialize(Jackson2HalModule.java:583)
    at org.springframework.hateoas.hal.Jackson2HalModule$HalLinkListDeserializer.deserialize(Jackson2HalModule.java:528)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(FieldProperty.java:136)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:369)
```

I tried serving this JSON locally so I can remove the next and prev links from it, and it works fine. I had a look in the code and it fails because it's trying to do `new UriTemplate(href)` which does not accept null as a parameter.

We are running Spring Boot version `2.1.8.RELEASE` and spring-hateoas version `0.25.2`. Below is the code that makes the request:

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    mapper.configure(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION, false);
    Jackson2HalModule jackson2HalModule = new Jackson2HalModule();
    mapper.registerModule(jackson2HalModule);

    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(MediaType.parseMediaTypes(Arrays.asList("application/json;charset=UTF-8", "application/hal+json")));
    converter.setObjectMapper(mapper);

    RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder = new RestTemplateBuilder();

    RestTemplate restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder.messageConverters(Collections.singletonList(converter)).build();

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set("Accept", "application/json, application/*+json");
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);

    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity(entity.toString(), headers);

    ParameterizedTypeReference<Resources<Panden>> typeRefDevices = new ParameterizedTypeReference<>() {};
    ResponseEntity<Resources<Panden>> result = restTemplate.exchange(endpoint, HttpMethod.POST, entity, typeRefDevices);;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending some time looking through the code of Jackson2HalModule I found a solution for this problem. There is no configuration that I can use to tell the library to simply ignore links that have null values. What I can do instead is override the deserialize() method so that I can add a null check and avoid the problem.

In order to do this firs I had to create the new link deserializer class. It needs to extend *Jackson2HalModule.HalLinkListDeserializer* then I just copy & pasted the code from the library source with the modifications I wanted.

```
public class CustomHalLinkListDeserializer extends Jackson2HalModule.HalLinkListDeserializer {

    @Override
    public List<Link> deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) 
                                      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        List<Link> result = new ArrayList<Link>();
        String relation;

        // links is an object, so we parse till we find its end.
        while (!JsonToken.END_OBJECT.equals(jp.nextToken())) {

            if (!JsonToken.FIELD_NAME.equals(jp.getCurrentToken())) {
                throw new JsonParseException(jp, 
                              "Expected relation name", jp.getCurrentLocation());
            }

            // save the relation in case the link does not contain it
            relation = jp.getText();

            if (JsonToken.START_ARRAY.equals(jp.nextToken())) {
                while (!JsonToken.END_ARRAY.equals(jp.nextToken())) {
                    CustomLink link = jp.readValueAs(CustomLink.class);
                    String href = link.getHref() != null ? link.getHref() : "http://dummy";
                    result.add(new Link(href, relation));
                }
            } else {
                CustomLink link = jp.readValueAs(CustomLink.class);
                String href = link.getHref() != null ? link.getHref() : "http://dummy";
                result.add(new Link(href, relation));
            }
        }

        return result;

    }
}
```

Then, in order to tell the Jackson2HalModule to use the new class I had to create my own MixInAnnotation class where I specify that links are deserialized using *CustomHalLinkListDeserializer*

```
public abstract class CustomResourceSupportMixin extends ResourceSupport {

    @Override
    @XmlElement(name = "link")
    @JsonProperty("_links")
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
    @JsonSerialize(using = Jackson2HalModule.HalLinkListSerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = CustomHalLinkListDeserializer.class)
    public abstract List<Link> getLinks();

}
```

The new MixInAnnotation can be set while configuring jackson2HalModule as below

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Jackson2HalModule jackson2HalModule = new Jackson2HalModule();
jackson2HalModule.setMixInAnnotation(ResourceSupport.class,
                                         CustomResourceSupportMixin.class);
mapper.registerModule(jackson2HalModule);
```